# The smallest value of |12^m-5^n|.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $m,n$ be positive integers. Find the smallest possible value of $|12^m-5^n|$.

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2519916p21374223). The minimal value is $12-5=7$. The last answer in the duplicate gives a solution, too.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).